# Robot framework UnicodeEncodeError: 'latin-1' codec can't encode character '\u201d' in position 13: ordinal not in range(256)

Tags: robotframework

I have Basic authentication testcase ongoing and I had this error: UnicodeEncodeError: 'latin-1' codec can't encode character '\u201d' in position 13: ordinal not in range(256)

```
${auth}=    create list    ${VALID DBUSER}    ${VALID DBPASSWORD}
Create Session    mysession    ${SERVER}     auth=${auth}
${get_response}=     GET On Session    mysession    accounts/login/
Log To Console    ${get_response.status_code}
```

How can I resolve this error?

I have Googled this problem but not found good Solution for this. Python version is 3.11.0

Comment: What keyword triggers the error ?

Comment: That character is" right double quotation mark". It is not the same as quotation mark. Maybe your input was changed by a word processor.

Comment: Keyword is GET On Session. On the password I have double quatation mark. Maybe Get On Session can’t process it right way.

Comment: I removed double quatation mark from the password and the testcase started to work. I think Get On Session can’t process double quatation mark right for some reason. Thanks for your answers and help!